# Classify csv files in different folders according to their name

Tags: command-line, files

I have a lot of csv files that I want to classify according to their filename in different folders.

1. Files called `*lefto.csv` will be saved in a folder called `lefto`
2. Files called `*righto.csv` will be saved in a folder called `right`
3. Files called `*sagital.csv` will be saved in a folder called `sagittal`
4. Files with names not obeying any previous condition, will be saved in a folder called `animals`

So far I have been using the `mv` command, but I would like to make a loop.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a `case` statement would be appropriate here. This should work in bash or other Bourne-like shells:

```
for f in *.csv; do 
  case "${f%.csv}" in 
    *.lefto) echo mv -- "$f" lefto/
    ;; 
    *.righto) echo mv -- "$f" righto/
    ;; 
    *.sagital) echo mv -- "$f" sagital/
    ;; 
    *) echo mv -- "$f" animals/
    ;; 
  esac
done
```

Testing:

```
touch foo.lefto.csv bar.righto.csv baz.csv foo.sagital.csv
```

then

```
mv -- bar.righto.csv righto/
mv -- baz.csv animals/
mv -- foo.lefto.csv lefto/
mv -- foo.sagital.csv sagital/
```

*Remove the* `echo`s *once you are convinced it is doing what you want*

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
mkdir -p lefto righto sagital
for prefix in lefto righto sagital; do
    mv -- *"$prefix.csv" $prefix/
done 
mv -- *.csv animals/
```